# Stuck with false XHTML output

Tags: jsf

I am trying to run a simple test XHTML in Wildfly, but unfortunately the browser (http://localhost:8080/testproj/test.xhtml) only shows the XML file and not its result. I use Maven for the dependencies and I run the Wildfly server on Ubuntu 14.04.2. Wildfly seems to deploy the `testproj.war` without errors.

I'm not sure whether to search the error in my Wildfly configuration or within my program code. Could anybody plz help me out?

My test.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head/>
    <h:body>
        <p:outputLabel value="my test output"/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Inserted part in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My installed Java version:

```
user@userpc:~$ java -version
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

EDIT [solved]:

Added lines to my web.xml. It now looks like this and parsing now works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Show the configuration of `FacesServlet` in web.xml and the URL you're using to access to the page.

Comment: Ok, I followed the duplicate link and solved my case. Will post it as an answer in a sec. Thanks a lot and sorry for duplicating! Wasn't sure how to search for this issue.